# how to delay JMS message in spring on weblogic 10.3 server

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, spring-jms

I want to delay message delivery by certain time which will be different for each message.

I referred [weblogic 10.3 WLMessage documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/weblogic/jms/extensions/WLMessage.html) which recommends using  `javax.jms.Message.getIntProperty("JMS_BEA_DeliveryTime")`.

However I'm unable to figure out how do I set `JMS_BEA_DeliveryTime` as `INTEGER`. I was expecting it to be `long`.

I'm unable to find out any documentation about this attribute `JMS_BEA_DeliveryTime` to undesratand how to set and use it. Can anybody give example about how to set the desired delivery time or link to documenation of use of this attribute.

My code looks like typical use of Spring JMS template:

```
 jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
                public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                  TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(textMessage);
                  return message;
                }
            });
```

I was wondering if it is possible to set header for delivery time before returning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Good article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/sending-delayed-jms-messages) with examples of delaying delivery for different JMS providers, include WL.

Comment: thanks for the link to article. It explains JMS scheduling quite nicely. However article explains about setting time on producer and not on each message. Also as per new weblogic documentation setTimeToDeliver method on message is deprecated.

Comment: so, i see two options: 1) replace WebLogic Jms implementation with different JMS implementation (HornetQ, for example) and 2) Replace Spring JmsTemplate with (maybe syncronized) bunch of code from article from my answer. Both of them isn't nice. However, i think property "JMS_BEA_DeliveryTime" will overrided by WLProducer, as described in documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/javadocs/weblogic/jms/extensions/WLMessage.html#setJMSDeliveryTime%28long%29 but nevertheless, it worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24401/pagehelp/JMSjmsmessagejmsmessagetabletitle.html) which states

```
JMS Delivery Time: The earliest absolute time at which 
                   a message can be delivered to a consumer.
```

It should be trivial to set with [Message.setIntProperty(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setIntProperty%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), there is not much mention as to what the time actually constitutes though, although I did find [this article](http://www.javamonamour.org/2011/07/weblogic-jms-scheduling-jms-message-for.html) which suggests milliseconds from now.

Hope that helps.